# CSS responsive error

Tags: html, css, mobile

I just don't know what happens with the background, on desktop it was fine, but when I try to resize the browser or view it on mobile, the background is no longer there.

[image: screenshot of desktop version]
*Screenshot of the desktop version.*

[image: screenshot of mobile version]
*Screenshot of the mobile version.*

--------- Style ----------------------

```
    header .menu-wrap{ background: #474749; margin-top: 20px}
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li{ float: right; background: #fff; border-left: 2px solid #fff; position: relative;}
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li:first-child{ border-right: 2px solid #fff;}
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li > a{ color: #fff; padding: 10px 16px; display: block; background: #474749; border-radius: 15px 0 0 0; font-size: 19px; font-family: 'Oron'}
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li > a:hover{ background:#fff000; color: #414042 }
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li:hover a{text-shadow: .0px 0px #000; }
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li .sub-menu{ position: absolute; background: #e6e7e8; display: none; width: auto; z-index: 9999}
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li .sub-menu li{ background: url(../images/bullet.png) no-repeat 130px center; padding-right: 20px; display: inline-block; float: right; width: auto; min-width: 120px;padding: 8px 18px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;} 
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li .sub-menu li a{ display: block; margin-right: 15px}
    header .menu-wrap .main-menu > li .sub-menu li:hover{ background: url(../images/bullet.png) no-repeat 131px center #fff000; color: #414042}
```

--------- HTML -----------------------

```
                <div class="menu-wrap">
                    <div class="grid-container">
                        <ul class="main-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">אודות</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">לימודים</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">מרכז מידע והרשמה</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">שירות לסטודנט</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="">עד 20 תווים 12 pt</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">עד 20 תווים 12 pt</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">סגל</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">כנסים ואירועים</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ספריה</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">מחקר עיון והוצלא</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">מעורבות חברתית</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add css where you specify the media-query background properties for mobile and desktop

Comment: Please can you provide your html and css, otherwise it is very hard to help you. I would check the @media styles in your css though.

Comment: Hi everyone, I just added the css and the html code, hope this can help, thanks

Comment: What I wanted is not really a responsive one, I just wanted the page to look the same as the desktop version

Comment: Are you talking about background image of the ENTIRE WEBSITE or just menu links? Because in your sample code, it seems like the only background images are for the menu links

Comment: yes I want the width of the background to fit with the width of the body on different screen or viewport

Comment: if you saying yes to "background image of the ENTIRE WEBSITE" look at the my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an image as a background attachment of the page you can do this:

**HTML**
Use a container div just below the opening of `<body>`:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     // your html code inside the container div
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**
put the background-attachment inside the container div, give the div a width of 100% not `px`, that way it will disply the same in every screen/viewport:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.amazonwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Big-Action-Spongebob-Squarepants-Cartoon.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but still the background just disappeared when I resize the browser

Comment: then il have to assume there is a media query somewhere in your css files which detected the screen resolution size and it take out the background image when it gets to a mobile screen size.

The only way to fix that is to pin-point the media query and modify/remove it.

Comment: I also tried it using a color background only, and the result is the same, I used "modernizr" library, and "normalize.min.css" does it have an effect on it?

Comment: I doubt its the libraries.. check all css files loaded by the browser somewhere there is a media query library.....

Comment: try using developer tools: 
**Chrome** press F12 (will open dev tools), then click on `Network` that will show you all files loaded by the browser

Answer (score -2):

Try to use boot strap theme, 
it is very easy and convenient to use ,
one of the good resources for responsive html.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html

Comment: Adding a whole new framework (and its associated overheads) is not required here. At all.